# HTML - Placing Headers Side By Side

Tags: html, css

I couldn't seem to put both of the headers next to each other in the same line. And also, I would like to align the headers to the center of the page.

Need help on this please.

```css
.inline-div {
  display: inline;
}

h4
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-div">
  <h4>Product Tested :</h4>
  <h4>Profile Tested :</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: These are called "headings" not "headers" which are something else, such as `<header>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.inline-div {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

h4
{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-div">
  <h4>Product Tested :</h4>
  <h4>Profile Tested :</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```css
.inline-div {
  display: inline;
}

h4
{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-div">
  <h4>Product Tested :</h4>
  <h4>Profile Tested :</h4>
</div>
```

By default headings are display:block; which means they occupy the entire line

Comment: "Headings" not "headers"

Answer (score 2):

```css
.inline-div {
  display: inline;
  
}

h4
{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-div">
  <h4>Product Tested :</h4>
  <h4>Profile Tested :</h4>
</div>
```

add `display: inline-block;` to `h4`

```
.inline-div {
  display: inline;
}

h4
{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

<div class="inline-div">
  <h4>Product Tested :</h4>
  <h4>Profile Tested :</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is also a different Solution from the first answers.

```css
.inline-div {
  display: table;
  text-align:center; 
  width:100%;
}

h4
{
  display:table-cell;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-div">
  <h4>Product Tested :</h4>
  <h4>Profile Tested :</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below css for `inline-div`. No additional css required for `h4`.

```
.inline-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .inline-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
</style>

<div class="inline-div">
  <h4>Product Tested :</h4>
  <h4>Profile Tested :</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.flexbox{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content:center;
  align-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
}

.item{
  align-self:auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height:12px;
  min-width:12px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item">a </div>
  <div class="item">b </div>
</div>
```